# Como poner en un bucle una importación [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy haciendo un programa repartido en pequeños programas, que luego importo en el final, pero al querer ponerlos dentro de un bucle infinito, solo se importa la primera vez.

Un ejemplo:

El programa 1 sería, por poner un ejemplo, este:

```
print(3+4)
```

Y luego desde otro programa importar el programa 1 infinitamente:

```
while True:
    import programa1
```

Al finalizar la primera vuelta del bucle, y empezar de nuevo el bucle, no se vuelve a importar el *programa1*.

Espero que se entienda.

Comment: Por que razon quieres hacer eso? No suele ser necesario.

Comment: Buen día ¿Cuál sería el motivo por el que quisieras importarlos más de una vez? Si quisieras crear "instancias" del código podrías utilizar clases

Comment: Era para no tener que abrir el programa cada vez, pero probaré con clases

Comment: Tampoco me funciona así (con clases)

Comment: O sea, lo que quieres hacer es ejecutar un programa de Python, cerrarlo y que se vuelva a abrir?

Comment: Quiero hacer un programa que importe repetidamente otro programa dentro de un bucle,  pero no se importa más de una vez.

Comment: ¿Pero cuál es el fin de hacer eso? Al importar un módulo en Python 3, se crea una referencia a ese módulo, si importas el mismo módulo multiples veces, no se crean múltiples referencias. Si usas el módulo `sys` e imprimes `sys.modules.keys()` vas a poder ver los módulos que se han cargado a tu programa. De esa forma puedes comprobar que un módulo que ha sido importado no "crea" una nueva referencia al importarlo nuevamente

Comment: ¿Puedes editar tu pregunta y agregar más información del comportamiento que deseas obtener? ¿Qué esperarías que sucediera al importar un módulo X veces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando importas un script por primera vez en una ejecución, Python lee y **ejecuta** el script. Los resultados quedan accesibles al resto del programa.

Un `def funcion(parametros)` es una instrucción **ejecutable**. El resultado es que ahora existe la función en cuestión y la puedes llamar.

El script también puede tener instrucciones sueltas, que no están dentro de ninguna función, clase o método. Por ejemplo, `print(3+4)` es una instrucción suelta que se ejecuta, pero sólo la primera vez que importas el módulo.

Lo que pretendes es que esas instrucciones se ejecuten repetidas veces, dentro de otro trozo de código. La manera de lograrlo es simple: pones la(s) instrucción(es) dentro de una función y luego la llamas cuando quieras repetir el cálculo.

En tu caso, sería

**programa1.py**

```
def inicializar():
    print(3+4)
```

En el programa `principal.py`, lo importas y ejecutas. Ojo, que ahora el `print` no se ejecuta al importar, ya que está dentro de una función.

**principal.py**

```
import programa1

...

while True:
    programa1.inicializar()
```